# MySQL Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset Loading a CSV file

Tags: c#, mysql

Trying to load a CSV file into a MySQL Database and I get a run time

```
Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
```

A similar question was asked here in April. I didn't see any replies but hoping someone else has seen this.
here is the command from the debugger:

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\SANCentral\\Customer Files\\ibm\\70738\\0918\\Switch 
Port.csv' INTO TABLE By_Switch FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\\r\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES"
```

Here is the C# code:

```
string ConnectionString =  String.Format(@"server={0};userid={1};
        password={2};database={3}", server, user, passwd, database);
        MySqlConnection sqlconnect = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        sqlconnect.Open();
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = this.InputFileListView.Items.Cast<FileInfo>();
        string commandstring = String.Format(@"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{0}' INTO TABLE {1} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES", 
                                                files.FirstOrDefault().ToString(), "By_Switch");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandstring,sqlconnect);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have verified that the column names in the database match the column names in the incoming CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out.   I used MySQL Workbench to run the same load command.  MySQL was more descriptive of the issues.  First, I had an incorrect data type on a column in the table.  Next, apparently if you say a line ends in \n but it ends in \r\n that is an issue.  In this file it appears there is a mix of \r\n and just \n.  So I guess I will have to normalize the line endings before loading files.  Finally, some of the actual data values are missing, so you get rows with ,, in them.  I am not sure what to do about that.